# Rotation increments are off on 3d object

Tags: matlab, rotation, octave, rotational-matrices

I can rotate an object about an axis but theta is very off
it should be rotating from 1 degree to 45 degrees in 1 degree increments but it's doing much more than that.  I converted theta (th) from degrees to radians but the issue still occurs.

Here's a link to the animation of the rotation
[image: animation of the rotation]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bnc7m4fxipicizr/rot2.gif

And the code is below:

```
clf 
[Z,Y,X] = cylinder(10:-1:0, 50);
xlabel('X axis')
ylabel('Y axis')
zlabel('Z axis')
array_sz_begin=size(X);
W=repmat(1,array_sz_begin); %create ones for w
figure(1), clf;surf(X,Y,Z);axis equal;
%--- z-rotation matrix Rz
for n=1:1:45
    th=n*pi/180; %angle of rotation converted to radians;
    Rz=[cos(th) -sin(th) 0 0;sin(th) cos(th) 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1];
    P=[X(:) Y(:) Z(:) W(:)]*Rz; %rotate each point on surface
    X=reshape(P(:,1),array_sz_begin);%transform surface vertices back
    Y=reshape(P(:,2),array_sz_begin);
    Z=reshape(P(:,3),array_sz_begin);
    xlabel('X axis')
    ylabel('Y axis')
    zlabel('Z axis')
    clear P;
    title(['Shift in ',num2str(n),' deg']);
    hold on;surf(X,Y,Z);axis equal;
    pause (.5)
end
```

PS I'm using octave 4.0 which is like matlab.

Comment: It's because you update `X`, `Y` and `Z` at each iteration while doubling the value of `th`. Try running the code without changing the value of `theta` in the loop

Comment: @BillBokeey if I don't change `th` (theta) how will I get any rotation?

Comment: You'll get a rotation of 1° at each iteration, which is what you want (Of course you'll have to define `th=pi/180` before the for loop). (Just try it)

Comment: @BillBokeey that worked if you submit it as the answer I'll mark it as being solved.  Thanks

Comment: Nah don't worry it was just a typo, no need for an answer. Take care

Answer (score 0):

Decided to post the solution in case someone has an issue like this.  All thanks goes to  `BillBokeey`

```
clf 
[Z_orig,Y_orig,X_orig] = cylinder(10:-1:0, 50);
xlabel('X axis')
ylabel('Y axis')
zlabel('Z axis')
array_sz_begin=size(X_orig);
W=repmat(1,array_sz_begin); %create ones for w
figure(1), clf;surf(X_orig,Y_orig,Z_orig);axis equal;
%--- define z-rotation matrix Rz

for n=1:1:90

    th=n*pi/180; %angle of rotation converted to radians;
    Rz=[cos(th) -sin(th) 0 0;sin(th) cos(th) 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1];
    %Rz=[cos(th) -sin(th) 0;sin(th) cos(th) 0;0 0 1];
    P=[X_orig(:) Y_orig(:) Z_orig(:) W(:)]*Rz; %rotate each original point on surface
    X=reshape(P(:,1),array_sz_begin);%transform surface vertices's back
    Y=reshape(P(:,2),array_sz_begin);
    Z=reshape(P(:,3),array_sz_begin);
    xlabel('X axis')
    ylabel('Y axis')
    zlabel('Z axis')
    clear P;
    title(['Rotate in ',num2str(n),' deg']);
    hold on;surf(X,Y,Z);axis equal;
    pause (.1)
  clear P
end
```